# Multiple lines instead of single line in HtmlEditFor() function? ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a few textboxes that work great with the HtmlEditFor (single line) but I have been asked to make the text-input-box larger for one of the inputs. How can I acheive this??

I want 6-8 lines. Currently my code looks something like this:

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

Comment: Have you tried using `@Html.TextAreaFor`?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, 10, 55, null)
```

10 is the number of rows and 55 is the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
```

Putting this over the inputs property in the model would allow for a larger box that can be manually rescaled.